# D3.JS V5: Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,242.20533333…"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to build a razor page that plot some charts.
After rendering the razor, the resulting Js is similar to this:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
...
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var jsonData = [{"date":"2017-11-30T00:00:00","Price":99.4 ... },{"date":"2017-12-01T00:00:00","Price":100.05}[

    // Use the margin convention practice 
    var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50}
        , width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right // Use the window's width 
        , height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom; // Use the window's height

    // X scale will use the index of our data
    var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([new Date(2017, 08, 1), new Date(2019, 11, 1)])// input
        .range([0, width]); // output

    // Y scale will use the randomly generate number 
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 150]) // input 
        .range([height, 0]); // output 

    // d3's line generator
    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(d.date); }) // set the x values for the line generator
        .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.Price); }) // set the y values for the line generator 
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX) // apply smoothing to the line

    // An array of objects of length N. Each object has key -> value pair, the key being "y" and the value is a random number
    // var dataset = d3.range(n).map(function(d) { return {"y": d3.randomUniform(1)() } })

    // Add the SVG to the page and employ #2
    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Call the x axis in a group tag
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisBottom

    // Call the y axis in a group tag
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisLeft

    // Append the path, bind the data, and call the line generator 
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(jsonData) // 10. Binds data to the line 
        .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling 
        .attr("d", line); // 11. Calls the line generator
```

In IE/Chrome I can see the axis but no plots. I can also see that it has a malformed path and I assume there is some problem with the dates, but I cannot figure out what the issue is

```
<path class="line" d="MNaN,242.20533333333327CNaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,239.0940000 ...
```

In firefox it only show the axis, without any errors
Any ideas what can be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `"2017-11-30T00:00:00"` with `new Date(2017, 11, 30)` to prevent the `NaN`.

[d3-time-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format) can also be used to parse date strings.

Comment: that is comming from a Razor rendering, so I cannot really change it, but I did this: `jsonData.forEach(function (item, index, theArray) {item.date = new Date(item.date)})`
and it worked! Thanks :)

Comment: @CarlosGarcia you could try to render as epoch time (long) instead of iso time (string), in order to skip the processing on the client-side. In every case, this needs to be a numerical and not a string value.